# Format a variable in math mode dependent on its case

Tags: math-mode, stringstrings

I have a special kind of variable in my equations which I want to be formatted **dependent on its case** (lower or upper).

I already tried using the package **stringstrings**, but there seem to be problems with math mode and grouping braces. In the example below it always chooses the *then-part*, ignoring whether the variable is lowercase or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\testStringstrings}[1]{\testlowercase{#1}\iflowercase{is lowercase}\else{is uppercase}\fi}

\newcommand{\specialvar}[1]{\testlowercase{#1}\iflowercase{\mathrm{#1}}\else{\mathbb{#1}}\fi} % always called within math-mode

\begin{document}

    % works fine
    t \testStringstrings{t} and T \testStringstrings{T}

    % does not work as expected (T should be formatted with \mathbb but is in \mathrm)
    \(\specialvar{t} \in \specialvar{T}\)

\end{document}
```

Is there a nice solution to solve this problem?

Comment: This bug in `stringstrings` has been resolved as of version 1.23, uploaded to CTAN on 2 FEB 2015 (http://ctan.org/pkg/stringstrings)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything weird will happen if you have more than one letter in the argument of `\specialvar` or something that's not a letter, but here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\specialvar}[1]{%
  \ifnum\lccode`#1=`#1
    \mathrm{#1}%
  \else
    \mathbb{#1}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\(\specialvar{t} \in \specialvar{T}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

There seems to be a bug in `stringstrings`, because with

```
\testlowercase{A}\iflowercase\LOWER\else\UPPER\fi
$\testlowercase{A}\iflowercase\LOWER\else\UPPER\fi$
```

LaTeX stops with

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 ...tlowercase{A}\iflowercase\LOWER\else\UPPER
                                                  \fi
```

in the first case, but with

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 $\testlowercase{A}\iflowercase\LOWER
                                         \else\UPPER\fi$
```

in the second case.

---

A workaround using `stringstrings`, which however adds an empty ordinary atom to the math formula (no side effect should arise, though):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\specialvar}[1]{%
  \mbox{\testlowercase{#1}\expandafter}\iflowercase \mathrm{#1}\else\mathbb{#1}\fi
} % always called within math-mode

\begin{document}

\(\specialvar{t} \in \specialvar{T}\)

\end{document}
```

The conditional is expanded before the empty box is finished, but the truth value is known.

A different workaround that doesn't add a math atom uses a temporary box and `\aftergroup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\testmlowercase[1]{%
  \sbox0{%
    \testlowercase{#1}%
    \iflowercase
      \aftergroup\lowercasetrue
    \else
      \aftergroup\lowercasefalse
    \fi
  }%
}

\newcommand{\specialvar}[1]{%
  \testmlowercase{#1}\iflowercase \mathrm{#1}\else\mathbb{#1}\fi
} % always called within math-mode

\begin{document}

\(\specialvar{t} \in \specialvar{T}\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for performing diagnosis on `stringstrings`.  Perhaps the patient is terminal 8^).

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: The bug in the `stringstrings` package that prompted the OP's query has been resolved in V1.23, uploaded to CTAN on 2 FEB 2015.  The answer below (developed prior to V1.23) provides the workaround for use with earlier versions of the package.

---

It's been too long since I looked at the code, but it seems that the test does not work in math mode, so to fix it for this case, I stuffed it in an `\mbox` and saved an intermediate flag.

And in case one wonders why I resort to an intermediate flag `\tmp`, it is to keep the actual output *outside* of the `\mbox`, which will allow it to take on the current mathstyle, as shown in the EDITED MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\testStringstrings}[1]{\testlowercase{#1}\iflowercase{is lowercase}\else{is uppercase}\fi}

\newcommand{\specialvar}[1]{%
  \mbox{\testlowercase{#1}\iflowercase{\gdef\tmp{T}}\else\gdef\tmp{F}\fi}%
  \if T\tmp\mathrm{#1}\else\mathbb{#1}\fi%
} % always called within math-mode

\begin{document}

    % works fine
    t \testStringstrings{t} and T \testStringstrings{T}

    % now works as expected (T should be formatted with \mathbb and it is)
    \(\specialvar{t} \in \specialvar{T}\)
    \(\scriptstyle\specialvar{t} \in \specialvar{T}\)
    \(\scriptscriptstyle\specialvar{t} \in \specialvar{T}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]